# How to SET CHAR() in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

My sample code is like

```
SET @myNumber = 65;
SET @myChar =  CHAR(@myNumber);
```

And when I select @myChar, the result is

```
| @myChar|
----------
| (BLOB) |
```

I want my code return like this

```
|@myChar|
---------
|   A   |
```

So any advice?

Comment: Works as expected for me. Have you told us everything? Any other technology involved or being written to a table maybe?

Comment: It's all that I typing in the query. I use Navicat premium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine with `MySQL 5.6`. However, I would recommend using `CONVERT` function if it casts to `BLOB` type by default, e.g.:

```
SET @myNumber = 65;
SET @myChar =  CHAR(@myNumber);
SELECT CONVERT(@myChar, CHAR);
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9deb/64/1)**.